# I am facing problem in navigation after splashscreen

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I tried using the following npm package suggested by a fellow developer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash
but when I build the project, I am stuck at my splash screen and my project does not proceeds further towards the navigation.

App.js file

```
export const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer onReady={() => RNBootSplash.hide(fade: true, duration: 500)}>
        <PrivateNavigation />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
```

Private Navigation Code:

```
export const PrivateNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routes.VENUE_PROFILE} component={VenueProfile} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routes.REVIEWS} component={Reviews} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routes.CUSTOM_TRIP} component={CustomTrip} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routes.TRIP_LOCATION} component={TripLocation} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routes.TRIP_DETAIL} component={TripDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen name={routes.NOTIFICATIONS} component={Notifications} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={routes.ACCOUNT_SETTINGS}
        component={AccountSettings}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavigationContainer onReady={() => RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true, duration: 500})}>
```

It seems like there might be a syntax error in your `NavigationContainer` component's `onReady` prop.

Comment: According to the documentation, I wrote the syntax correctly